# How to solve C++ conflicts between system and library dependencies

Tags: c++, g++, mips, cross-compiling, linkage

My problem is rather specific, but bear with me.
This in the end is kinda reverse engineering, but this problem in particular seems to fit more this board.

So, I have a shared object compiled for MIPS written in C++. I don't have the source code of the lib. The lib is compiled using `GCC` 4.3.3. I want to use functions present in this shared object in my amd64 computer running elementary OS. To do this, I used the sourcery cross compiler to cross compile some C++ code to MIPS, that would use this object.

So far I managed this except for this one compile error, which I cannot figure out. The lib is called libdvl.so, and uses as dependency libc.so.0 (and both are in the same folder as the cpp code).

```
mips-linux-gnu-g++ -g -L/path/to/lib -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib -o verifier verifier.cpp -ldvl
```

which gives me

```
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libc.so.0, needed by /path/to/lib/libdvl.so, may conflict with libc.so.6
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: errno@@GLIBC_PRIVATE: TLS definition in (...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../mips-linux-gnu/libc/lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS definition in /path/to/lib/libc.so.0 section .bss
/path/to/lib/libc.so.0: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I added "-l:libc.so.0" and got this

```
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: errno: TLS definition in (...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../mips-linux-gnu/libc/lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS definition in libc.so.0 section .bss
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../mips-linux-gnu/libc/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea how to solve this? I know I am using `GCC` 4.9.1, but I already downloaded the older code sourcery version which uses `GCC` 4.3.154 and got the exact same error.

**EDIT 1:** Exactly as Lol4t0 said, filtered using c++filt it gives an actual function name from stdc++. Using

```
mips-linux-gnu-g++ -g -L/path/to/lib -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib -I/path/to/lib -o verifier verifier.cpp -ldvl -l:libuClibc++.so.0 -l:libutil.so.0 -l:libc.so.0 -l:ld-uClibc.so.0 -nodefaultlibs
```

to give to libdvl its depencies (as I will not rewrite stdc++ :p), I get the following compile error:

```
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.9.1/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc66DLda.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0'
(...)/mgc/embedded/codebench/bin/../mips-linux-gnu/libc/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already confirmed lib dependencies and the order in which they appear.
Any thoughts on this?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: A wild guess: did you try to compile with `-pthread`?

Comment: I think you need to add `-nodefaultlibs` to your compile line to inhibit the default library from being linked.

Comment: The `-pthread` thing did no change :/

Comment: However, the `-nodefaultlibs` did it :D now I get ` undefined reference to symbol '_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc'` which I guess is something related to the absence of the lib's header

Comment: OK then now you need to make sure your `-I` include path points to the standard library includes packaged with `/path/to/lib`.

Comment: _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc means `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)` and iws a part of c++ library. Do you use C++ in your project, or lib itself references thif function. Because you probably will not make work new stdc++ with old libc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are linking against GLIBC (`libc.so.6`) *and* some other libc (`libc.so.0`).

That could *never* work: you have to have everything compiled and linked against a *single*, *consistent* libc.

Since your `libdvl.so` uses as dependency `libc.so.0`, and assuming you can't rebuild `libdvl.so`, you *have to* use crosscompiler that targets `libc.so.0` (which is possibly dietlibc, or uClibc), and compile and link everything else using that toolchain. Your crosscompiler on the other hand appears to target GLIBC, and will not do you any good.

After a lot of trial and error, you may be able to link the final binary using inconsistent builds, and your binary may even get to `main` (that is very unlikely). But chances of such binary actually working correctly are minuscule.

Comment: Thanks. Compiling/linking is kinda not my area, and what you said makes perfect sense. I was hoping that the compiling step would separate the actual code from its dependecies; the code would be compiled using lic.so.6, and when calling libdvl, the libdvl calls would go to the libc.so.0.

Answer (score 2):

Using `-nodefaultlibs` solves the first problem though.